# R 3.0.3 rbind multiple csv files

Tags: r, csv, rbind

R 3.0.3: I have 40 csv files all structured the same that I want to `rbind` into one file so I can calculate the mean of one column.

I searched:

- this website
- `R in a Nutshell`
- `R_Intro` sources
- `?rbind Help` in RStudio

I cannot find the answer.

Any suggestions/pointers?

Answer (score 20):

Using the answer from here [[Importing several files and indexing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836946/importing-several-files-and-indexing-them) ]

list files with .csv extension - this assumes that the only .csv files in your working directory are the ones you want to read

```
files  <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv')
```

read files into a list - are there headers?

```
tables <- lapply(files, read.csv, header = TRUE)
```

rbind  files

```
combined.df <- do.call(rbind , tables)
```

You can then find the **mean** - find which columns are numeric

```
s <- sapply(combined.df, is.numeric)
```

find the mean of numeric variables

```
colMeans(combined.df[s])
```

Comment: .@user20650 - Thank you for your answer. If before `rbind()`, I want to add a unique identifier (numeric like 0,1,2 etc) that can help me distinguish which data is from file 1 and which is from file , then how can I achieve this? I am currently trying `loop()`, but it's getting a bit messy.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil ; at the read in stage, you could add the file names with `tables <- lapply(files, function(x) cbind(read.csv(x, header = TRUE), id=x))`, or a numeric with `tables <- lapply(seq_along(files), function(x) cbind(read.csv(files[x], header = TRUE), id=x))` ; or using `data.table` in the  list as in the answer above : `names(tables) <- files ;  data.table::rbindlist(tables, idcol=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

In more contemporary plyr approach:

```
files <- list.files(...)
data <- adply(files, 1, read.table)
```

(it's saturday afternoon: untested code, but the approach is fine)